# why data are passing back but SwiftUi not updating Text

Tags: swift, swiftui, callback

I get to pass back data via closure, so new name is passed, but my UI is not updating. The new name of the user is printed when I go back to original view, but the text above the button is not getting that new value.

In my mind, updating startingUser should be enough to update the ContentView.

my ContentView:

```
@State private var startingUser: UserData?
        
var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Text(startingUser?.name ?? "no name")
            Text("Create start user")
                .onTapGesture {
                    startingUser = UserData(name: "Start User")
                }
        }
        .sheet(item: $startingUser) { userToSend in
            
            DetailView(user: userToSend) { newOnePassedFromWhatDoneInEDitView in
                startingUser = newOnePassedFromWhatDoneInEDitView
                print("✅ \(startingUser?.name)")
            }
        }

}
```

my EditView:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var user: UserData
    var callBackClosure: (UserData) -> Void

    @State private var name: String
    

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("your name", text: $name)
            }
            .navigationTitle("edit view")
            .toolbar {
                Button("dismiss") {
                    var newData = self.user
                    newData.name = name
                    newData.id = UUID()

                    callBackClosure(newData)
                    
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
       
    
    }
    
    init(user: UserData,  callBackClosure: @escaping (UserData) -> Void ) {
        self.user = user
        self.callBackClosure = callBackClosure
        _name = State(initialValue: user.name)
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView(user: UserData.example) { _ in}
    }
}
```

my model

```
    struct UserData: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
        
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        
        static let example = UserData(name: "Luke")
        
        static func == (lhs: UserData, rhs: UserData) -> Bool {
            lhs.id == rhs.id
        }

}
```

update

using these changes solves the matter, but my question remains valid, cannot understand the right reason why old code not working, on other projects, where sheet and text depends on the same @state var it is working.

adding

```
@State private var show = false
```

adding

```
.onTapGesture {
      startingUser = UserData(name: "Start User")
      show = true
      }
```

changing

```
.sheet(isPresented: $show) {

                DetailView(user: startingUser ?? UserData.example) { newOnePassedFromWhatDoneInEDitView in
                    startingUser = newOnePassedFromWhatDoneInEDitView
                    print("✅ \(startingUser!.name)")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you add the definition for `UserData`?

Comment: updated with user model

Comment: Why not using a simple binding instead of creating multiple sources of truth?

Comment: still learning SwiftUi, sometimes I saw this way instead of binding, so I made an example, but is not working, so I'd like to understand why.

Comment: I´m not on my mac to cofirm this. But it is probably due to the `Equatable` implementation. For SwiftUI changing the name doesn´t change the `UserData`s identity so it won´t update.

Comment: tried to change it, but no result, I found a solution by changing the way sheet updates, but I still do not understand the problem, same logic elsewhere is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248265/discussion-between-biggreentree-and-burnsi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `Text` is not showing you the updated user name that you are passing in the closure is, your `startingUser` property will be set to **`nil`** when you dismiss the sheet because you have bind that property with `sheet`. Now after calling `callBackClosure(newData)` you are calling `dismiss()` to dismiss the sheet. To overcome this issue you can try something like this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var startingUser: UserData?
    @State private var updatedUser: UserData?
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(updatedUser?.name ?? "no name")
            Text("Create start user")
                .onTapGesture {
                    startingUser = UserData(name: "Start User")
                }
        }
        .sheet(item: $startingUser) { userToSend in
            DetailView(user: userToSend) { newUser in
                updatedUser = newUser
                print("✅ \(updatedUser?.name ?? "no name")")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would suggest you to read the Apple documentation of [`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) and check the example from the **Discussion** section to get more understanding.

Comment: thank you for explanation!!, it is working, so the matter is that mi closure was erased by the dismiss? I thought @escaping would have kept in memory my data. I'll definitely check your link.

Comment: @biggreentree Not your closure, `startingUser` itself will be nil as soon as you dismiss the sheet because you have binding `startingUser` to sheet(item:). So when you set value to `startingUser` it will present `sheet` when you set nil it will dismiss the sheet or if you dismiss the sheet then it will set `startingUser` to `nil`, I have already mentioned this in answer

Comment: Yes I am reading docs, the matter is, I still miss where is the reason why if in detailView I dismiss, startingUser will be set again to nil I mean, it is erased just because is binded?

Comment: @biggreentree Read the declaration of the `item` parameter and also check example where they are setting `sheetDetail = nil` to dismiss the sheet, If you set item binding to nil, it will dismiss the sheet, if you dismiss manually by sliding down or by handling `dismiss()` it will make `sheetDetail = nil`. Considering this will clear your doubt.